# Android: what is the difference between Fragment !isDetached() and isAdded()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Fragment, I want to make a Toast once some data is loaded, like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toast_loading_done,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This only makes sense if the Fragment is still attached to the Activity, i.e. the Fragment is visible and getActivity() will not return null.

I could check that with `!isDetached()` or with `isAdded()`, right? Here I am wondering what the difference between the two methods is and which one I should preferably use?

Comment: there is not such method like isAttached() in the fragment..

Comment: There is only `isDetached`.

Comment: As far as I know there is onAttached and isAdded.. please where did you see isAttached() ?

Comment: why not just simply do an if test? `if(getActivity() != null) { ... }`.

Comment: @all: my mistake! What I meant was actually `!isDetached()`. See the edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `Fragment` can be attached to an `Activity` without being added to it's view hierarchy.

If a `Fragment` is detached, it's state is maintained and can be re-added.

Comment: Where do you see that the state is maintained after it is detached? [According to the doc here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) onDetach is called last, after even onDestroy. After onDetach, the fragment is destroyed, there is no going back to an active state.