# What is the differences between onAttach() and isAdded() in android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone tell me what are the different of use of onAttach() and isAdded in Android Fragment?

When create a new fragment onAttach() method creating default.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729072/android-what-is-the-difference-between-fragment-isdetached-and-isadded) question, the question is asked about !onDetech() and isAdded() , also one answer there, but I am not clear with that.. 
Thanks

Comment: @Abhinav, That question is asked about !onDetech() and isAdded(), my question is about default onAttach() and isAdded().
Also, there is no clear answer on for that question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This could be answered simply reading javadocs:

```
    /**
     * Called when a fragment is first attached to its context.
     * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will be called after this.
     */
    public void onAttach(Context context)
```

and

```
    /**
     * Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.
     */
    final public boolean isAdded()
```

Answer (score 2):

- [**`onAttach()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context))

Called when a `fragment` is first attached to its `context`. `onCreate(Bundle)` will be called after this.

- [**`isAdded ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isAdded())

`Return true` if the `fragment` is currently added to its `activity`.

Answer (score 1):

`onAttach()` is called when a fragment is connected to an activity. Where `isAdded()` override method will come up with true if it is connected successfully to an activity.